# vcentre re-install

Tags: vmware-vsphere, disaster-recovery, vmware-vcenter

I am just reviewing our dr documentation after we have moved over to a vmware vsphere environment. My question is surrounding the vcentre software and what is the best practice to re-install this? We have two VMware clusters (one at main office and one at DR site both with their own SAN) and the vcentre software that controls these clusters is installed on a physical server at our main office. My thinking in DR would be to re-install onto a new server at the DR suite and perform a SQL recovery of the database. Is it that simple?? Would the server have to have the same network name?

My other thought for the future would be to maybe make the vcentre server a virtual box, that way I could mount a clone of this at the DR site, but I read so many arguments for and against this, so will need to think and investigate a little further before I comit.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

thanks

peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used to run our VC's on physical servers with their very expensive heartbeat software but we realised that with the advent of =>12-core CPUs and VS's ability for 8-way SMP it made more sense to run them in a VM. Of course this means that there's a chance that if a host dies we lose VC for the time it takes to reboot but we can live with that, you may not be able to. We also VM our VC DB server (Oracle on RHEL if you're interested) that way we can backup the who lot using VCB/Commvault although if you could live with running your MSSQL DB inside the same VC VM this would make things a lot simpler to recover. It all depends how important 24/7 VC availability is and if your load would support running the DB with the VC.